# Ask for advice - How should I intergrate Facebook SDK into Clean Architecture in Android?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, clean-architecture

I am using the [Clean Architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) in my currently project. Now I want to integrate a feature that request Facebook SDK to execute login.

Im my opinion, Facebook SDK acts as a Data-Provider (which provide authentication service, similar to other Restful login API) and should be setup and using under `data` module instead of `app` module. For example if I want to execute Facebook Login, I will invoke appropriate use-case, then such use-case will call `data` module to do actual work.

But, the challenge is Facebook method (see Facebook's LoginManager, [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/) ), require Activity/Fragment instance to run.

So, should I move Facebook SDK back to `app`module or pass the Activity instance down to `storage` module?

I don't really like any options of them. (felling not happy although it helps to resolve requirement). Does anyone have any better approach?
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Although it's the question about architecture, it's related to Android coding specific also. @ישואוהבאותך

Comment: did you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to strictly follow clean architecture u have to keep all frameworks out of ur inner circles (app module). This includes Facebook SDK as well as Android itself.

The usual way to access frameworks from business rules in Clean Architecture is trough abstractions.

In ur use case I would suggest the following:

- create IActivity interface in app module to abstract activity/fragment
- create ILoginManager in app module which takes IActivity
- create AndroidActivity which implements IActivity in framework layer
- create FacebookLoginManager which implements ILoginManager in framework layer
- from ur android activity when calling the use case interactor pass the activity as IActivity and the FacebookLoginManager as ILoginManager
- the FacebookLoginManager would then have to cast IActivity back to the android activity and pass it to the LoginManager from Facebook SDK

This approach would add some more classes and interfaces to ur project but also clearly separate concerns and dependencies.